# How do you create multiple forms in a Visual Studio 2019 Windows Forms project?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 creating a C# windows project. When I attempt to create an additional form by Project /Add Windows Form, a windows form is not an available in the selection box.[VS 2019 Add Item Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCGFy.png)

The same process in Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition will have "Windows Form" as an object to select. [VS 2017 Add Item Selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15S5p.png)

Does anyone know how to add multiple forms in VS 2019?

Comment: Have you tried selecting the "Windows Forms" node under the "Visual C# items" node? The items are not shown in alphabetical order, you might have to scroll down to find "Windows Forms".

Comment: The Windows Forms node does not contain a plain old Windows Form control.It only contains "Inherited Form" and "Inherited User Control". This node is also present in Visual Studio 2017, with the same content. I have found it necessary to go back to VS 2017 to add a second form, then I can open the solution in VS 2019 and proceed with my work. Looks clearly like a bug to me, it seems like Micorsoft wants to charge me $495 to report it!?

Answer (score 0):

(a bit late, but in case anyone googles it up like I just did)

Indeed, my Add Item Dialog does not even contain that "fake" Form item.

This solution is admittedly a bit hacky as it involves forcing the new form into the project manually. First, open the project folder and duplicate the existing form file, as well as the designer file. Rename the form class in those files so that it does not clash with the existing form. Do not add them to your solution just yet.

[image: Project folder]

Of course, that is not enough for VS to recognise the files as a form and let you open that in the Designer. For that reason, open the .csproj.user file in Notepad. It should look something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="MainWindow.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Duplicate that bit as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="MainWindow.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Update="ParameterWindow.cs">
      <SubType>Form</SubType>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

When you open the solution in VS now, the files should be included and recognised as a form (and from my observation, the .resx file should be automatically generated at that point).